# Java reading decrypted file - file not found exception

Tags: java, servlets, java-io

I am trying to read decrypted property file.

File location is `/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties`

Decoder java file is `src/a2.util/Decoder.java`

which has method called `readFile(String fileName)`.

When I call the method like this:

```
Decoder.readFile("db.properties")
```

I got file not found exception. saying..

```
db.properties (System cannot find specified file)
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Resources are not files, and `/WEB-INF/classes` is not the current working directory when your servlet executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access as above.

You can get real path as:

```
ServletContext context = this.getServlet().getServletContext();     
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties");
```

OR

```
java.net.URL url = [ClassName].class.getClassLoader().getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties");
```

Unless try with this as:

```
InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties");
```

OR

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
```